# Prove that any strongly connected graph with n nodes has at least n directed edges.

Tags: graph-theory

I know that a directed graph is said to be strongly connected iff every pair of vertices in the graph are reachable from one another in both directions. However, I am not sure how to prove the above statement.

Comment: What can you say about the out-degree of a vertex, if you know there is at least one path starting at that vertex and ending at some other vertex?

Comment: If I know that there is at least one path going out from a vertex then the out-degree of a vertex is at least 1. But I am unsure how we can use this info to prove the statement above.

Comment: the sum of the out-degrees is equal to the number of edges @KimmySmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note the following: The number of arcs in $G$ is the sum of the outdegrees of $G$.

If then, for every vertex $y \in G$ and every other vertex $z$ there is a dipath $P$ from $y$ to $z$, then $y$ must have outdegree at least 1 i.e., the first arc in $P$. Can you finish from there.

Comment: How does the outdegree help me prove this statement? Would you mind elaborating a bit more on how outdegree would be helpful? Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned yet, that the number of edges in a digraph is the sum of the outdegrees

Comment: @KimmySmith : If each of $n$ vertices has an outgoing edge, there are at least $n$ edges (since, definitionally, each directed edge has one outgoing end and one ingoing end).

Comment: Oh I see, I remembered that now. It makes more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @KimmySmith Glad I could help!